# How to create deployment.xml file in ear application which used IBM websphere?

Tags: java, websphere, ear

I want to create deployment.xml file for my .ear application. I am new to IBM websphere environment. Please guide me for same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

deployment.xml is generated when the application is installed on the WebSphere server.  Once your app is installed, the file (which should never need to be hand-edited) can be found in your profile under config/cells/(cellname)/applications/(appname)/deployments/(appname).